# How to find double quotes in string in C#

Tags: c#, string

If a string has double quotes,

```
string str = "it is a "text""
```

how can I find out if the string have " or not.

And how can the double quotes be removed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 string str = "it is a \"text\"";
 string str_without_quotes = str.Replace("\"", "");
```

Don't bother checking if it contains quotes, just replace them.

Answer (score 18):

To check whether it contains the quote: `str.Contains("\"");`

To remove the quotes: `str.Replace("\"","");`

Comment: Or `str.Contains(@"""")` for people who really like having lots of quotes side-by-side.

Comment: @zneak, why would I want to do that. I still have nightmares about putting quotes in strings in VB6 where """" was the only option. I am so glad I don't have to do that anymore. And making a string of things in quotes """item1""""item2"""...

Answer (score 2):

To remove `str = str.Replace("\"", String.Empty);`

Answer (score 1):

```
bool containsQuote = str.Contains("\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget good old (char)34!  It can be used instead of the "\"" and the @"""" too!